# Why the geodesic curvature is invariant under isometric transformations?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As I know the geodesic curvature
$$
\kappa_g = \sqrt{\det~g} \begin{vmatrix}  \frac{du^1}{ds} & \frac{d^2u^1}{ds^2} + \Gamma^1_{\alpha\beta}  \frac{du^\alpha}{ds} \frac{du^\beta}{ds} \\  \frac{du^2}{ds} & \frac{d^2u^2}{ds^2} + \Gamma^2_{\alpha\beta}  \frac{du^\alpha}{ds} \frac{du^\beta}{ds} \end{vmatrix}, 
$$
where $g$ is the metric tensor, $\Gamma^v_{\alpha\beta}$ is [the Christoffel symbols of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols).

And [the first fundamental form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form) of the surface $I = (du^1, du^2) g (du^1, du^2)^T$. I think $I$ is invariant under isometric transformations but not the metric tensor $g$. So why $\kappa_g$ is invariant under isometric transformations?

Answer (score 1):

$ \kappa_g$ depends purely on the coefficients of the first fundamental form ( of surface theory FFF) and their derivatives, second fundamental form SFF coefficients are not involved.

It is invariant in isometric mappings ( bending transformations) like lengths,angles,  $K$ Gauss curvature , integral curvature etc. Liouville's theorem gives the expressions. Reference of text books of Differential geometry.

$K$ is an exception where the determinants of SFF and FFF can be used to  derive it in  the Gauss Egregium theorem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a well known sequence of isometric transformations of the (left-handed) Helicoid into the Catenoid back into the (right_handed) Helicoid. I've put in examples of the  principal lines of curvature,  which are both geodesics . The drawing isn't perfect , the surfaces lying on the right and left sides are missing a red straight line ( a geodesic)  down the center line of the helicoid. (Compare the central line on the Catenoid -- a circle ), from edge on the blue lines of the Helicoid are also straight lines.  Incidently the drawing is quite large, you can get a better idea of it by taking it down off of your screen.

A reference for $\kappa_g$ is "Lectures on Classical Differential Geometry" by Dirk J. Struik ( Chapter Four , Geometry on the Surface ,
pp. 128 ). It is shown that geodesic curvature depends only on E,F,G hence it is an invariant under isometric transformations, or a bending invariant as it is called in the text.

Comment: Thanks! $I = E (du^1)^2 + 2F du^1 du^2 + G (du^2)^2$ is invariant under isometric transformations but not $E, F, G$, so why the 'geodesic curvature depends only on $E,F,G$ hence it is an invariant under isometric transformations'?

Comment: Oh, no -  the first fundamental form for the Catenoid and the Helicoid are different for example. Also, generally when one says depends only on E,F,G one means also the first and second derivatives of E,F,G.

Comment: This link works for me, there is some good material :    http://books.google.com/books?id=TIXg4hSXmFAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false     Take a look at chapter four.